# Mongoose C++ HTTP server example gives mg_open_listen failure

Tags: c++, mongoose

I am attempting to run the Mongoose C++ basic HTTP Server code (https://mongoose.ws/documentation/tutorials/http-server/) based on their latest github master branch - on Windows in a Visual Studio project and I get an error for mg_open_listen. I don't think the issue is with the code, I just don't understand why I am getting the error for the socket creation.

Here is the console:

```
Starting HTTP listener on http://localhost:8000
271275e 1 mongoose.c:4315:mg_open_liste setsockopt(SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE): 10022
271275e 1 mongoose.c:3346:mg_listen     Failed: http://localhost:8000, errno 0
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mongoose.h"

static const char* s_listen_on = "http://localhost:8000";
static char s_web_root[512] = ".";

static void eventCallback(struct mg_connection* c, int ev, void* ev_data, void* fn_data)
{
    if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_MSG)
    {
        struct mg_http_message* hm = (struct mg_http_message*)ev_data;

        if (mg_http_match_uri(hm, "/"))
        {
            mg_http_reply(c, 200, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n", "Hello, %s\n", "world");
        }

        struct mg_http_serve_opts opts;
        memset(&opts, 0, sizeof(opts));
        opts.root_dir = s_web_root;
        mg_http_serve_dir(c, ev_data, &opts);
    }
    (void)fn_data;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct mg_mgr mgr;
    mg_mgr_init(&mgr);
    printf("Starting HTTP listener on %s\n", s_listen_on);
    mg_http_listen(&mgr, s_listen_on, eventCallback, NULL);

    for (;;)
    {
        mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 1000);
    }

    mg_mgr_free(&mgr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mongoose native code is C. so tagging C is within reason. It doesnt matter what port I use, it's always the same error. I have tried 80,800,5500, 8800, 8001, 8443, etc, etc.

Comment: If I am using a source that is C, it makes plenty of sense to tag C since someone that codes in C may have experience with the issue I am seeing. The issue is not with my code, it is with the source I am using. Therefor, C....

Comment: My code will run as C or a C++. It's ambiguous. If you have a solution that will work, Great, be a help and offer assistance instead of being rude and complaining that I tagged both when both languages are valid tags. - That is not helpful.

Comment: *My code will run as C or a C++.* Your code can't compile as C due to `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am attempting to run the Mongoose C++ basic HTTP Server code based on their latest github master branch.

The `master` branch is unstable and can have bugs. Actually, it has a bug and the fix is being reviewed: [Use `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` on Windows, as intended #2124](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/pull/2124).

If you don't develop Mongoose, use the latest release [Mongoose 7.9
Latest](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/releases/tag/7.9).